# LDAP (JNDI) backed data service in wso2 data services server

Tags: ldap, wso2, jndi, wso2-data-services-server

We'd like to create services in WSO2's DSS that query LDAP data.  The Data Services Server gives the option of creating JNDI backed data sources, but the data query definition seems to assume that all JNDI data sources use SQL (as evident by the query field being labled SQL).

The old WSO2 forums suggest that it's possible... http://wso2.com/forum/thread/11109

Does anyone have an example?
thx
Liam

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot use JNDI to expose LDAP data as LDAP doesn't expose its data as a database .. If you want samples on JNDI Data Sources and Exposing Data Sources as JNDI Resources, Please refer [1](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS300/JNDI+Data+Sources) and [2](http://docs.wso2.org/display/AS510/Exposing+Data+Sources+as+JNDI+Resources). If you want to expose your LDAP data and create data services you can use Data services [custom data source feature](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS300/Custom+Data+Sources) and implement it.